# initWithCalendarIdentifier no concrete implementation?

Tags: objective-c, calendar, ios7, abstract-class

Upgrading an app to iOS7, I have the following code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

I am getting:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCalendar initWithCalendarIdentifier:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper initWithCalendarIdentifier:]!'

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currentCalendar method of NSCalendar returns a fully initialized NSCalendar instance, so you don't need to init it. You should just do:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```

FYI, this was also true in iOS6; there was never any need to call an init method on the value returned by `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`.

If you just want to create a new Gregorian calendar instance, unrelated to currentCalendar, you can do:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

Comment: Thank you. Those are helpful suggestions. I am trying to understand why the line I posted in my question has no run time error in iOS6 but does in iOS7

Comment: [NSCalendar currentCalendar] returns a __NSCFCalendar instance in iOS6, which presumably implements the initWithCalendarIdentifier: method. In iOS7, it returns a _NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper, which apparently does not.

Comment: And anyway, you should never call an init method on an instance of an object for which an init method has already been called.

Comment: Thank you. I have  experience with dotNet, fairly new to ObjC, so not initing twice totally makes sense to me. Just as background, this is the previous developers code Ive just started looking at and have been asked to upgrade to iOS7. I now wonder if it was a total error on their part to do the init or whether there was some subtle reason behind it. I shall make yours the accepted answer. Thanks again.